# multiple selection with dependency in php using select2 in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am using **select2** plugin for selection.

I have multiple forms with employee name and three multi selection box for location department and position in each form, where each employee has multiple locations and in each location can have multiple department and position, means department and position are dependent on location with respect to each employee.

Department and position are shown in optgroup for location under which department and position are shown as option

**Problem**

I saved all values to my database.
how to show all selected values of location, department, and position with respect to the employee when I am in edit part.

[image]

Comment: if my suggested answer helps you then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

the saved values and coming in array
 So, you need to just put this condition

```
echo '<option value="$value"';
if(in_array($value,$array)) echo 'selected';
echo '>$name</option>';
```

Comment: Thanks for response,but how can i set location in optgroup for department and position

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your selected multiple locations in `select2` in edit form then this is the solution.

If you save the selected locations in the database as like this. `location1,location2..`

Then on the edit side.

```
var location_array= location_string.split(', ');                
$('#your_select2_id_of_location').val(location_array).trigger("change");
```

This will show the previously selected option in selct2 as selected.

Hope it will help.